# Django- How can I add sizes for my product?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, e-commerce

I created my models but now I don't know how to create a form with all the sizes I added for every product to add it to detail view. can you please help me, Thanks.

here is my models.py.

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import reverse

class Size(models.Model):
    size = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.size

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/product_cover', blank=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField(Size, through='ProductSize')
    datetime_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    datetime_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product_detail', args=[self.id])

class ProductSize(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new file named 'forms.py' in the same directory as your 'models.py'

in forms.py file:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Product, Size, ProductSize

class ProductSizeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductSize
        fields = ['size', 'count']
```

in your views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .forms import ProductSizeForm
from .models import Product, ProductSize

def product_detail_view(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)

    # If the form is submitted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductSizeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Save the form with the current product and add the size
            product_size = form.save(commit=False)
            product_size.product = product
            product_size.save()
            # you can redirect to a different page after successful submission
            # return redirect('success_view')

    # If the form is not submitted or the form submission is invalid
    else:
        form = ProductSizeForm()

    context = {
        'product': product,
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'my_product_size/product_detail.html', context) # I named the app "my_product_size"
```

in product_detail.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ product.title }} - Product Detail</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ product.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
    <p>Price: ${{ product.price }}</p>

    <h2>Add Size</h2>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Add Size</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('details/<str:product_id>', views.product_detail_view, name='product_detail')
]
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **forms.py**

```
from .models import Product,Size

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
#this will show dynamic checkbox form
    sizes = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Size.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

**In views.py :**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ProductForm

def add_product(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            product = form.save()
            return redirect('your_url_name')
    else:
        form = ProductForm()

    context ={'form': form}
    return render(request, 'product_add.html',context )
```

add_product.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Add Product</button>
</form>
```

Similarly create your urls.py.